# Java String.replace() or StringBuilder.replace()

Tags: java, string, performance, stringbuilder

In scenarios where I am using 5-10 replacements is it necessary to use stringbuilder.

```
String someData = "......";
someData = someData.replaceAll("(?s)<tag_one>.*?</tag_one>", "");
someData = someData.replaceAll("(?s)<tag_two>.*?</tag_two>", "");
someData = someData.replaceAll("(?s)<tag_three>.*?</tag_three>", "");
someData = someData.replaceAll("(?s)<tag_four>.*?</tag_four>", "");
someData = someData.replaceAll("(?s)<tag_five>.*?</tag_five>", "");
someData = someData.replaceAll("<tag_five/>", "");
someData = someData.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Will it make a difference if I use stringBuilder Here.

Comment: `replace` not use regex, use `replaceAll`, and you can use a chaine or replaceAll instead for example `string.replaceAll(..).replaceAll(..).replaceAll(..)`

Comment: Yeah Sure, I can use ReplaceFirst as well.

Comment: beside, why you don't want to use a single regex instead? i see many common parts

Comment: [RegEx for XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/501011), eh?

Comment: I have very small and simple xml. I think regex won't be a problem. @DavidStockinger

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `StringBuilder` won't make a useful difference here.

A better improvement would be to use a single regex:

```
someData = someData.replaceAll("(?s)<tag_(one|two|three|four|five)>.*?</tag_\\1>", "");
```

Here, the `\\1` matches the same thing that was captured in the `(one|two|etc)` group.

Comment: Yeah, that's neat. Changing as you suggested Is stringBuilder needed or not?

Comment: I don't know what advantage you think `StringBuilder` would confer here. You're doing regex replacement, which isn't supported by `StringBuilder`. Just stick with `String`.